# Filter Chain HTTPSecurity 5 to 6 Migration

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-3

I'm currently trying to migrate from Spring 2.x -> 3.1.5 as a beginner to Spring Security and I don't really understand the migration instructions.

Can someone explain the exact difference between the old requestMatchers and the new securityMatchers? The code attached below is the old version, but requestMatcher no longer works. Would the commented out parts be equivalent to the lower part?

```
//http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest());
//http.securityMatcher().authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest());
http.requestMatchers().anyRequest();
```

Would be thankful for each answer :)

Comment: Can you provide a full `configuration` method before starting migration ? it will be more easy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As a start you have to check [Migration Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html) where you will be able to find an answer to your question:

> In Spring Security 5.8, the antMatchers, mvcMatchers and
> requestMatchers methods from HttpSecurity were deprecated in favor of
> new securityMatchers methods.

It mean that you have to replace next one piece of code that you put in question:

```
//http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest());
//http.securityMatcher().authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest());
http.requestMatchers().anyRequest();
```

To the next one:

```
http.authorizeHttpRequests(AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry::anyRequest);
http.securityMatcher().authorizeHttpRequests(AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry::anyRequest);
http.securityMatchers(AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry::anyRequest);
```

More details about it you could find in above reference to Migration Guide.

Comment: I migrated 

from: http.requestMatchers().anyRequest();

to: http.securityMatcher().authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeHttpRequests) -> authorizeHttpRequests.anyRequest());

Is this wrong?

Comment: `requestMatchers` -> `securityMatchers` all that you need it is. You have to try on your own that you have added. Also you could use my recommendation that I gave you as a answer to the question. Don`t forget to read migration guide.

Comment: thanks in advance for your help. Yes i was reading it but I would need a deeper understanding of each function to know if my migration replace the old chain correctly. I will just try my changes now.

Comment: You are welcome, let me know if you deal with it.